# Georeferencing las files using liblas

Tags: georeferencing, lidar, c++, las, liblas

I am trying to write georeferencing information to a '.las' file using liblas and c++.

Here is my code:

```
   ofstream ofs;
   ofs.open("test.las", ios::out | ios::binary);
   liblas::Header header;
   liblas::Writer writer(ofs, header);

   liblas::Point point(&header);
   point.SetCoordinates(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);

   writer.WritePoint(point);
   header.SetPointRecordsCount(1);

   liblas::SpatialReference srs;
   srs.SetFromUserInput("EPSG:4326");
   header.SetSRS(srs);
   writer.SetHeader(header);
   writer.WriteHeader();
```

But, when I check the file using lasinfo tool I get:

```
 Spatial Reference:           None
```

If I check proj4, the information is stored, so I don't know why lasinfo doesn't print it:

```
Code  : std::cout << srs.GetProj4() << std::endl;
Output: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

However, when I use lasinfo tool with others las files not written by me I can see the WKT and geotiff output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write a lasfile with SRS information, you must create your `liblas::Writer` using a `liblas::Header` that has a defined SRS. Change your code to this:

```
ofstream ofs;
liblas::Header header;
liblas::SpatialReference srs;
srs.SetFromUserInput("EPSG:4326");
header.SetSRS(srs);
header.SetPointRecordsCount(1);
ofs.open("test.las", ios::out | ios::binary);
liblas::Writer writer(ofs, header);

liblas::Point point(&header);
point.SetCoordinates(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);

writer.WritePoint(point);
writer.WriteHeader();
```

## Explanation

libLAS's header writer implementation [does not modify any VLRs when in append mode](https://github.com/libLAS/libLAS/blob/eb35d1adc2cca1c2a9cafd4e57c979378e596abc/src/detail/writer/header.cpp#L100). libLAS also [writes the header immediately upon creating a new writer](https://github.com/libLAS/libLAS/blob/eb35d1adc2cca1c2a9cafd4e57c979378e596abc/src/writer.cpp#L67), which ensures that all subsequent calls to `Header::write()` are [considered to be in append mode](https://github.com/libLAS/libLAS/blob/eb35d1adc2cca1c2a9cafd4e57c979378e596abc/src/detail/writer/header.cpp#L86). Therefore, you must set up your header with the appropriate spatial reference system (and other VLRs) before creating the writer.

IMO this could be a bug. If you feel the same way, [open an issue](https://github.com/libLAS/libLAS/issues) on libLAS and see what they have to say.